# How do I use Firebase in an external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, firebase

This is probably a very simple issue, but I've been trying to use Firebase in an external javascript file that is being used with an HTML file and can't get it to work properly. I am planning to use this file for many other similar pages, so I'd rather keep it in an external document. Specifically, my code is:

```
$(function() {

var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.src= 'https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js';
head.appendChild(script);

var Database = new Firebase('https://myfirebase.firebaseIO.com/');
...
```

but when I try to run it, it says that the Firebase object/keyword is undefined. I know that the script is being correctly appended to the HTML page because I've checked the HTML on the page after running the code.

I have also read somewhere that you might need to have a personal server to run Firebase, but frankly I don't really know what that means - in any case, I use Mac OSX and run all of my HTML and Javascript in Chrome.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use jQuery getScript with the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that using document.createElement does not force the script to be loaded and rendered before your inclusive script is invoked (it's being invoked now). There are no guarantees by this method on when the script you include will get invoked.

Additionally, you are loading the script onDomReady by putting it inside `$(function() {...})`; you would want to insert it into the header immediately, not wait for the entire document to load.

The simplest answer is to just put Firebase into the head of the html page; you haven't really explained your limitations here, but I assume this isn't an option for you. If it is, KISS.

Another simple answer is to utilize jQuery, since you obviously have it available.

```
$.getScript('https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js', function() {

    // now I can use Firebase

});
```

You can also accomplish this with other methods (wait until Firebase is defined using a setInterval; utilize other script retrieval methods besides document.createElement--try googling "load scripts dynamically via javascript load order"), but I think this covers your needs sufficiently.

Comment: Thank you very much, the JQuery function made it work! I'm curious, does the getScript command automatically run before onDomReady?

Comment: Nice answer Kato!

Note that getScript automatically busts caches, so for best performance, you might want to just use jQuery.ajax with dataType:"script" and cache:true

Comment: @user2170663 The getScript command runs when the browser reaches the line of javascript on which it's written. The DOM may or may not be loaded at this point, but at least you're not explicitly waiting for the DOM to load before fetching the script. Does this make sense?

Comment: @bennlich great point; but the DOM doesn't need to be loaded for any of the above, just jQuery, and as long as it is not also being dynamically included, you're good to go.

Comment: @user2170663 getScript runs whenever you execute it; whether it runs onDomReady or before would just depend on where you put it in the calling script